# Iversion equivalent for titanium

Tags: ios, titanium-mobile

I need a way to check the app store for the latest update of the app.

One way of doing this is to make an api call to see what the latest version is and force the user to download it. However this is reliant on an internet connection; a better way is to sync the app with the app store. There is a native module called iversion, does anyone know of a titanium equivalent.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iVersion

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Harpy project](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy) the [benCoding.iOS.Tools module](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.iOS.Tools) allows you to query the AppStore and return the latest version. Check README for further details.

Comment: Awesome, is this module compatible with 64 bit?

Comment: Also how can I test it without the app being on the app store?

Comment: Just checked it is not 64 bit compatible :(

Comment: You may want to grab the existing source and add [iOS Module 64-bit Support](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/iOS+Module+64-bit+Support).

Comment: Followed the instructions, keep getting a build error. Is it possible if you could kindly build it for 64 bit for me?

Comment: You either didn't update the **TITANIUM_SDK_VERSION** in titanium.xconfig with a recent SDK (3.5.0.GA or 3.5.1.GA) or simply accepted recommended updates (the ! symbol in the window title).

Comment: I just accepted recommended updates, isn't that the way to do it?

Comment: Ok made the changes, pressed the play button in x code, it has built it, but I have no idea where the files are. Can't seem to find them.

Comment: That will only build your Project but it would not generate the distribution module

Comment: Check this [module guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Quick_Start-section-43288582_iOSModuleQuickStart-BuildandPackagetheModule) for overall instructions. I'm in the middle of something and can't dig into the issue now but feel free to bring up the StackOverflow question adding more possible details to help you out troubleshooting the problem.